# Can't resolve all parameters for service

Tags: angular, rest, web-services

I tried to create a generic service to call my API and build is giving me that error :

> Can't resolve all parameters for DataService in /ng-app/src/app/services/data.service.ts: (?, [object Object]).

I know i'm not the first who got it but everything I found didn't help.

Here is what i tried :

- Checking if @Injectable was correct
- Not using the barrel
- Using types in constructor params
- Tsconfig.json emitDecoratorMetadata set to true
- All services are registered in the Providers part of the ngModule

I don't know what else I could try to fix it ...

Here is some code :

DataService :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AppError } from '../common/validators/app-error';
import { NotFoundError } from '../common/not-found-error';
import { BadRequest } from './../common/bad-request-error';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private url: string, public httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getAll(){
    return this.httpClient.get(this.url).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  getOne(ressource){
    return this.httpClient.get(this.url + '/' + ressource).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  create(ressource){
    return this.httpClient.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(ressource)).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  update(ressource,oldRessource){
    return this.httpClient.put(this.url + '/' + oldRessource, JSON.stringify(ressource)).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  delete(ressource){
    return this.httpClient.delete(this.url + '/' + ressource).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  public handleError(err: Response){
    if (err.status == 400 ){
      return Observable.throw(new BadRequest(err));
    }

    if (err.status == 404) {
      return Observable.throw(new NotFoundError());
    }
    // Return error by default if no specific error
    return Observable.throw(new AppError(err));
  }
}
```

A service extending from DataService

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CategorieService extends DataService {

  constructor(httpClient: HttpClient) { 

    super('http://localhost:8081/categories' ,httpClient);

  }
}
```

UPDATE:

I got I have to use a ToketInjection pattern to solve my issue. I also used environments classes to avoid having to setup the base URL at different places.

But I still don't get how i can now change that URL in my DataService for each Services extending from DataService.

Here is some code :

App.module.ts :

```
...

import { CategorieService } from './services/categorie.service';
import { DataService } from './services/data.service';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';


export function getBaseUrl(): string {
  return environment.API_BASE_URL;
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    ])
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
    DataService,
    CategorieService,
    { provide: 'API_BASE_URL', useFactory: getBaseUrl },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Environement.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  API_BASE_URL: "http://localhost:8081/",
};
```

Data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AppError } from '../common/validators/app-error';
import { NotFoundError } from '../common/not-found-error';
import { BadRequest } from './../common/bad-request-error';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  //constructor(private url: string, public httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  constructor(@Inject('API_BASE_URL') private url, public httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getAll(){
    return this.httpClient.get(this.url).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  getOne(ressource){
    return this.httpClient.get(this.url + '/' + ressource).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  create(ressource){
    return this.httpClient.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(ressource)).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  update(ressource,oldRessource){
    return this.httpClient.put(this.url + '/' + oldRessource, JSON.stringify(ressource)).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  delete(ressource){
    return this.httpClient.delete(this.url + '/' + ressource).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  public handleError(err: Response){
    if (err.status == 400 ){
      return Observable.throw(new BadRequest(err));
    }

    if (err.status == 404) {
      return Observable.throw(new NotFoundError());
    }
    // Return error by default if no specific error
    return Observable.throw(new AppError(err));
  }
}
```

I would like to add some parameters to my base API URL the same way i tried to do it before to be able to reach specific parts of my API but i don't get how to do that with TokenInjection.

Answer (score 1):

You *don't really wanna put a string in your constructor*. You could do something like an [injection token](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken) or putting that string as a const in your environments file and then importing your environments as as a provider like they did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48182290/how-to-inject-api-base-url-a-string-in-an-angular-service).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and keep you updated. I foud an easy to follow tutorial here : https://medium.com/coding-blocks/power-of-angular-dependency-injection-b981faa9c0de :)

Comment: I did read about it and there is still something i don't get. How can i pass this token from my service extending from my DataService to my DataService ?

Comment: @Ishiru can you update your original question to see how you're using the injectionToken?

Comment: I did provide an update, you can see i also used Environement classes to setup the base URL