# Can't resolve all parameters for AuthService on Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to start my angular app and i'm getting this error below for some reason. I tried removing the **auth service** provider from my component and removing also the auth service from my constractor inside my component, but nothing changed... I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong and i'm beginner on angular.

**The error:**

```
Can't resolve all parameters for AuthService: (?, ?, [object Object]).
```

**My component:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../../Services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  providers: [AuthService]
})

export class LoginComponent {

  isUserLoggedIn: boolean;
  emailAddress: string;
  password: string;
  invalidLogin: boolean;
  invalidText: string;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {

    if (authService.getCurrentUser() != null) {
      router.navigate(['/home']);
    }
  
  }

  login() {
    
    if (!this.authService.login(this.emailAddress.toString(), this.password.toString())) {
      this.invalidLogin = true;
      this.invalidText = "Wrong Email Address or password";
    }
    
  }

}
```

**My service:**

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserModel } from "../Models/UserModel";

export class AuthService {

    constructor(private router: Router, private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) {}

    login(email: string, password: string) {

        const headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', };
        const body = { emailAddress: email, password: password };
        let userLoggedIn: Boolean = false;

        this.http.post<any>(this.baseUrl + "Api/Login", body, { headers }).subscribe(response => {
            
            if (response.username != null) {
                let user: UserModel
                user = response;
                this.router.navigate(['/home']);
                this.saveUserToLocalStorage(user);
                userLoggedIn = true
            }

        }, error => console.error(error)); 
        return userLoggedIn;
    }

    saveUserToLocalStorage(loggedInUser: UserModel) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("loggedInUser", JSON.stringify(loggedInUser));
    }

    getCurrentUser() {
        return sessionStorage.getItem("loggedInUser")
    }

    logout() {
        sessionStorage.removeItem("loggedInUser")
        this.router.navigate([''])
    }

    createUser(userData: UserModel) {}

    sendResetPasswordEmail() {}

}
```

Comment: Try injecting this `@Inject('BASE_URL` to your app component. Is it works there? btw, returing a `usesrLoggedIn` from `login` method will not work the way you wanted....

Comment: @robert I added `@Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string` to my component constructor but it doesn't work

Comment: can you share the source where you provide `BASE_URL' ? Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51542180/2050306) answer

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you use `Router` in your constructor, try to do this

```
constructor(private readonly injector: Injector,
           ...) {}

public get router(): Router {
   return this.injector.get(Router);
}
```

Comment: Check my answer, i had to make my service injectable

Answer (score 0):

I found what was the problem. I had to mark my service class as `@Injectable()`

**Like this:**

```
@Injectable()
export class SchoolService {
  ...
}
```